# How to Write an Active record Query for Count and Union

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I wrote a query to get count of entries in SQL table
I was using active record in CodeIginitor

This code is not working ... saying error in query line

```
$this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM site UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userdata'); 
$result=$this->db->get();
return $result->result();
```

I searched to get a corresponding active record query but have not got any result

Comment: change query to this:- `$this->db->query('(SELECT COUNT(*) as count_site FROM site) UNION (SELECT COUNT(*) as count_userdata FROM userdata)');`

Comment: @AlivetoDie it got edited later. nvm though ;)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya it's ok.no issue

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this query?  Do you need the number of rows in each table or the total rows?

Comment: You need to give different alias names to `COUNT(*)` in your query, otherwise it will throw error

So do like this:-

`$this->db->query(
        '(SELECT COUNT(*) as count_site FROM site) 
        UNION 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) as count_userdata FROM userdata)'
);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 $this->db->query(
    '(SELECT COUNT(*) as count_site FROM site) 
    UNION 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as count_userdata FROM userdata)'
 );
 return $query->result();
```

Comment: Your code snippet seems to be helpful, but you should explain what is wrong with the OPs code and how you fixed it.